# RecyclerView View error On PreferanceActivity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to show alertdialog on preferencactivity, But the recyclerview shows like this.
[image]

My code....

```
 cata_manage.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(preference.getContext());
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)preference.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cata_manage, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = dialogBuilder.create();


            final RecyclerView cata_list = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cata_manage_recycler);

   update_recycler_cata("Expenses", cata_list,preference.getContext());
            alertDialog2.show();

            return false;
        }
    });




 private void update_recycler_cata(String cata, RecyclerView catalist,Context context) {
    DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor catas = null;
    if (cata == null || Objects.equals(cata, "Expenses")) {
        catas = mydb.fetchall_cata_ex_names();

    } else if (Objects.equals(cata, "Income")) {
        catas = mydb.fetchall_cata_in_names();
    }
    CataRecyclerAdapter adapter = new CataRecyclerAdapter(catas, context, catalist);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);


    catalist.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    //  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    catalist.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**CataRecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public class CataRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CataRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
private Cursor cursor;
private Context context;
private RecyclerView catalist;

CataRecyclerAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context, RecyclerView catalist) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.context = context;
    this.catalist = catalist;

}

@Override
public CataRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.catamanage_singleitem, parent, false);


    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);

    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CataRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.item.setText(cursor.getString(1));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageButton edit, delete;
    TextView item;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        item = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        edit = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        delete = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    }
}
}
```

My inflating XML...[image]

XML code (catamanage_singleitem.xml)...

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView34"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I ve tried many ways, How can i solve this issue.? I ve added a imageview inside `catamanage_singleitem` but that imageview is not showing. How can i solve this, is this due to that the context value i take.?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: i ve updated my question

Comment: Can you post recyclerview's list item.xml and update_recycler_cata method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(preference.getContext());
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cata_manage);
final RecyclerView cata_list = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cata_manage_recycler);
update_recycler_cata("Expenses", cata_list,preference.getContext());
dialog.show();
```

**EDIT**

Change `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"` to `app:src ="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"` in `Imageviews`

Comment: It's `setContentView`, I've updated the answer. sorry my bad

Comment: still the same... NO success

Comment: Try now and if it's not working paste your xml code for item and layout